# JSON Schema - How can I conditionally refer to the JSON file based on the field value

Tags: arrays, json, schema, jsonschema

```
    {
        "operation": {
                       "type": "string",
                       "enum": ["create","update"]
         },
        "payload": {
    // I have to add json file refs: based on the value of operation(create,update)
        }
    }
```

If operation is create than ("$ref": "create" ) json file.

If it's update than ($ref - "update") json file

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on which draft you are using.

draft-04:

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "operation": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["create"]
            },
            "payload": {"$ref": "create"}
        },
        {
            "operation": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["update"]
            },
            "payload": {"$ref": "update"}
        }
    ]
}
```

draft-06 (note the `"const"` in place of the one-element `"enum"`s):

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "operation": {
                "type": "string",
                "const": "create"
            },
            "payload": {"$ref": "create"}
        },
        {
            "operation": {
                "type": "string",
                "const": "update"
            },
            "payload": {"$ref": "update"}
        }
    ]
}
```

draft-07 (published on Monday so not yet implemented really) introduces `"if"`/`"then"`/`"else"` which offers several other ways to do the same thing.  But `"oneOf"` is pretty clear in this case, I think.

Answer (score 2):

New version of avro allow the  "if"/"then"/"else" condition